# How can I block "PUA.Http.Exploit.CVE_2015_1692"

Tags: command-line

I've been running Clamtk pretty regularly because my ubuntu 14.04 keeps bringing this "PUA.Http.Exploit.CVE_2015_1692" after each scan. I found that it is considered a Trojan in microsoft operating systems. What is said to do to microsoft system is happening to my ubuntu system as well. While surfing the web, at first it works fine, and then it bogs down, freezes going from web page to web page it becomes annoying. Just wondering what I could do to prevent this thing from popping up after each scan.

Comment: Are you running a web browser (IE) under Wine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing after almost every clamAV scan. It is a browser related issue. I'm guessing you're using Firefox? Try different browser and then scan your system. You can also have a look in here: 
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/581481/clamtk-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this particular PUA is linked to gmail.com/ googlemail.com.
I cannot suggest what creates the other PUA's that Firefox acquires after a small amount of browsing that ClamAV identifies, but, clear your Firefox cache after every session and this should get rid of these unwanted PUA's.
Linux is inherently safe, I have faith in it, and the added peace of mind that ClamAV brings, however, I think that it can fuel a little bit of 'paranoia' about what has 'slipped in through the back door'
Clear browser cache, see if that works for you.